# Deploying a Kubernetes application on Azure VM scale sets

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-vm-scale-set

Has anyone here successfully set up a Kubernetes application on an Azure VM scale set and exposed the app?

If so, what steps did you take to expose the app?

Comment: You shouldgo for AKS https://azure.microsoft.com/es-mx/blog/introducing-azure-container-service-aks-managed-kubernetes-and-azure-container-registry-geo-replication/

Comment: Hi there! Do you have a specific reason why you need scale sets, or you simply want a Kubernetes cluster on Azure? I'm asking because there are a couple of ways to easily get a Kubernetes cluster on Azure - first and easiest is to use a [managed Kubernetes cluster with AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/) - you only manage and pay for the agents, not the master. Another way, that gives you more flexibility is to use [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/deploy.md) - let me know if this gets you closer to our answer.

Comment: @radu-matei Well, I already have Kubernetes setup on the scale set so now I have a master scale set and a node scale set with 3 nodes which together form a Kubernetes cluster. But I've had endless trouble trying to expose a Kubernetes application on the cluster due to the loadbalancer issue - as Kubernetes uses a service with a loadbalancer to expose its apps. I was just wondering if someone had successfully been able to do this or if everyone is just using AKS or acs-engine for their Kubernetes applications on Azure.

Comment: The way I see it, most of the people will use AKS, as it is a managed service (and you don't pay anything for masters + are managed) - however, if you need to cusomize that in any way (change container runtime, custom VNETs or different networking driver), acs-engine gives you this option, while still being completely configured to use Azure load balancers and storage classes and overall much easier to deploy compared to a bare Kubernetes.

Comment: @radu-matei Right, I see. Thanks for your clarification!